# Number of triples that are connected by exactly 2 edges in a random graph

Tags: random-variables, random-graphs

In a random graph $G(n,p)$ where $n\geq 3$, let $S$ be the number of triples of nodes that are connected by exactly $2$ edges.

For example, if node $1$, node $2$ and node $3$ are connected by exactly $2$ edges, then $\{1,2,3\}$ is considered as one of the triples.

Find $E[S]$.

There can be at most $n$ such triples and at least 0 triples. Therefore, 
$E[S]=\sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot \text{Pr}(S=k)$.

Now the problem is that I don't know how to determine $\text{Pr}(S=k)$.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that there are at most $n$ triples connected in this manner? There are a total of $\binom n3$ triples, and while that upper bound might not be attainable, it is possible to have more than $n$. As an example, take the fully connected graph at $n=5$, and choose 3 vertices. Delete all edges between those 3, as well as the edge connecting the other 2. The resulting graph has exactly 9 such triples by my count.

Comment: @Kajelad Yes, you are right. Now I am more confused since I cannot even determine the maximum number of triples.

Comment: You could just use $\binom n3$. The probability term would just be zero for sufficiently large values of $S$. Calculating the probability of an individual triple having 2 edges is trivial; the issue is that the probabilities are interdependent in a way that is hard to account for, since each triple shares an edge with $3n-9$ other triples. Some kind of elaborate induction on $n$ is needed, I think.

Comment: @Kajelad Yes. I am trying now to see if there is any pattern.

Comment: @Kajelad Since there are $n \choose 3$ possible triples. We denote $X_i=1$ if the $i$-th triple satisfies our requirement. Then $E[S]=\sum_{i=1}^{n \choose 3} E[X_i] = {n \choose 3} P(X_i=1) = {n \choose 3} {3 \choose 2} p^2(1-p) $? $X_i$ are not independent but they are identically distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume a random graph with $n\;$vertices, such that each potential edge has probability $p$ of being an actual edge.

Let $f(n,p)$ be the expected number of qualifying triples.

There are $\large{\binom{n}{3}}$ candidate triples.

Each candidate contributes $0\;$or $1$ qualifying triples to the count of qualifying triples, hence each candidate contributes its probability of qualifying to the expected number of qualifying triples.

Then the probability that a randomly chosen candidate triple qualifies is
$${\small{\binom{3}{2}}}p^2(1-p)$$
hence, since there are $\large{\binom{n}{3}}$ candidate triples, it follows that
$$f(n,p)={\small{\binom{3}{2}}}p^2(1-p){\small{\binom{n}{3}}}$$

Comment: Why is ${n \choose 2}^3$ in the denominator in the probability that a randomly chosen candidate triple qualifies? $p$ is the probability that an edge exists. Hence, there is no need to divide by ${n \choose 2}$.

Comment: Right, that was a leftover from the previous version -- will fix it -- thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I also figured it out in the comment of the question.

Comment: Ah, so I see. Then +1 for you as well!